# Nagios Reports Down Then Up Immediately after

Tags: ubuntu, nagios

I've been using Nagios to monitor a bunch of servers for about a year. It's been great. But recently, Nagios started emailing me that every host was down. Then, immediately after, would tell me every host was OK.

It does this all day, every day. I wake up in the morning to 40+ emails.

Nagios.log shows these lines, which seem to pertain to the down-up situation, for a single one of my urls:

```
[1505007529] SERVICE ALERT: myurl.com;/;CRITICAL;HARD;1;HTTP CRITICAL: Status line output matched "200" - 48479 bytes in 10.223 second response time
[1505007529] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;myurl.com;/;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;HTTP CRITICAL: Status line output matched "200" - 48479 bytes in 10.223 second response time
[1505007579] SERVICE ALERT: myurl.com;/;OK;HARD;1;HTTP OK: Status line output matched "200" - 48479 bytes in 0.197 second response time
[1505007579] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;myurl.com;/;OK;notify-service-by-email;HTTP OK: Status line output matched "200" - 48479 bytes in 0.197 second response time
```

The alert seems to be where it realized something was down. The notification seems to be where it issued the email to me. Then alert for back up. Then email for back up.

Now, here is the command I'm using to monitor the url:

```
define command{
   command_name    check_http_url
   command_line    $USER1$/check_http --expect="200" -w 5 -c 10 -t 20 -H $ARG1$
}
```

I thought that maybe the servers couldn't respond to the ping fast enough. So, I wanted to increase the time Nagios would tolerate waiting for a response.

Therefor, I added the -w, -c, and -t to debug the issue. It was acting like this for a month before I tried adding those. These didn't seem to help with anything.

Here is what my service definition looks like:

```
define service{
    host_name                       myurl.com
    service_description             /
    max_check_attempts              1
    check_interval                  1
    retry_interval                  1
    check_period                    24x7
    notification_period             24x7
    notification_interval           10
    check_command                   check_http_url!myurl.com
    notifications_enabled           30
    contact_groups                  admins
    contacts                        nagiosadmin
    notification_options            w,u,c,r
    }
```

Let me just say again, this worked great for over 7+ months. Then, started acting up on it's own. I didn't personally change any config once I got it working initially.

If it were only reporting a single server, I'd be willing to accept that the monitored server might be slow to respond. But most often it will come back with 3-4 of my servers as down and then back up at the same time. This leads me to think the issue actually with the nagios environment, and not the other servers.

Thank you in advance for helping me debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Just some opinion,
Sometimes latency high will cause Nagios ping==Fail

First, check network:
Can you check your network environment with ping script, continuous ping, when ping fail or latency is high, record it on log. Just want to confirm there is no loop or something blocked between Nagios and other servers.

Second, check Nagios server:
If network works fine, you can simply setup Nagios server on other server to monitor, make sure it's your Nagios server problem or not.